# Error in eclipse when running activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am starting to program for android, when I first try to run the application from eclipse IDE it worked fine, but now I am getting the following error:

```
emulator: ERROR: unexpected qemud char. channel close
```

I didn't change the configuration or the code i had, also the activity is not starting in the emulator and I can't debug.

Can someone tell me what this error means?

Thanks

Comment: is there emulator display when you have run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try to delete the AVD & create a new one
sometimes it keeps saving errors in a log then those errors become permanent
try to create a new emulator then test again

Comment: Thanks, that helped, do you know what might had caused it?

Comment: It's a bug in the emulator I guess whenever this happens just create a new AVD